# Cannot find 'Conekta' in scope iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

Estoy intentando integrar el `SDK de Conekta` en mi aplicación de `iOS`

https://github.com/conekta/conekta-ios

https://developers.conekta.com/page/ios-skd

y recibo este mensaje:

> "Cannot find 'Conekta' in scope"

Cabe destacar que generé mi bridging-file, asigné la información a mi Library Search Patch y Copié todos los archivos de la carpeta "Conekta" dentro de mi proyecto... Solicito ayuda para solucionar mi problema. ¡Muchas gracias!

Pd. Mi entorno es iOS 14 en XCode 12 con Swift 5

Comment: Agregaste los archivos de la carpeta "Coneckta" a Xcode?

Comment: si, de hecho la documentación es "sencilla" por eso no entiendo realmente qué podría estar saliendo mal :(

Comment: Bastante sencilla. Tienes o se te creó un archivo con extensión `.xcworkspace`? Si es así debes trabajar en ese.

Comment: Pero ese . xcworkspace es el de mi proyecto principal ¿no? porque su repo tiene uno

Comment: Y ninguno de los dos funciona?

Comment: No amigo :/ intenté haciendo otro proyecto y tampoco

Comment: Lo logré, tenía un Bridging-Header antes y no me había dado cuenta, estaba creando otro... 

Mil gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes agregar esa respuesta y marcarla como la solución. Así ayudas a otras personas con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema estaba en el uso de los `Bridging-Header` ya que había utilizado uno con anterioridad dentro del mismo target. Un `Bridging-Header` permite enlazar código de `Swift` y `Objective C` y tener varios en un mismo target puede causar conflictos si no lo has configurado así. Si eres principiante, recomendaría utilizar un mismo `Bridging-Header` por cada target

Para más información:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896751/can-should-i-have-more-than-one-objective-c-bridging-header